Solution to a Quadratically Constrained Quadratic Program (QCQP) with unit ball constraint

I am working on a Quadratically Constrained Quadratic Program (QCQP) of the form:$$ \min_{x} \quad \frac{1}{2} x^T P x + q^T x + r$$
$$ \mathrm{subject\ to} \qquad x^{T}x \leq 1   $$
where $P \in S^{++}_{n}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix, and $q \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a given vector. I aim to show that the optimal solution $x^{*}$ satisfies:$$ x^{*}=-(P+ \lambda I)^{-1}q$$
where $ \lambda$ =$max\{ 0,\bar{\lambda}\}$ and $\bar{\lambda}$ is the largest solution to the nonlinear equation:$$q^{T}(P+\lambda I)^{-2}q=1 $$

I tried solving this by using the necessary and sufficient conditions for the optimal solution:$$ x \ is \ optimal \ if \ and \ only \ if \ x \in X \ and
\\
\nabla f_0(x)^T (y - x) \geq 0 \quad \text{for all} \quad y \in X.
$$
But I wasn't able to make progress.Is there an alternative approach to solve this problem, or any hints on how to use the optimality conditions more effectively? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Hint: use the KKT conditions (which are necessary because Slater's CQ holds)

We have
$$f := \frac12 x^\top P x + q^\top x + r
= \frac12 (x + P^{-1}q)^\top P (x + P^{-1}q) + r - \frac12 q^\top P^{-1}q.$$
If $q^\top P^{-2} q \le 1$, then
clearly the minimum of $f$ is $r - \frac12q^\top P^{-1}q$ when $x^\ast = - P^{-1}q$.
In what follows, assume that $q^\top P^{-2} q > 1$.
Let $h(\lambda) := q^\top (P + \lambda I)^{-2}q - 1$. We have
$h(0) = q^\top P^{-2} q - 1 > 0$
and $h(\infty) = -1$. Also, we can prove that
$h'(\lambda) < 0$ on $(0, \infty)$.
Thus, there exists a unique $\lambda_0 > 0$ such that $h(\lambda_0) = 0$ i.e.
$q^\top (P + \lambda_0I)^{-2}q = 1$.
We have, for all $x^\top x \le 1$,
\begin{align*}
 f &\ge f - \frac12\lambda_0 (1 - x^\top x)\\
 &= \frac12 x^\top (P + \lambda_0I)x
 + q^\top x + r- \frac12 \lambda_0\\
 &= \frac12 (x + (P + \lambda_0I)^{-1}q)^\top
 (P + \lambda_0I) (x + (P + \lambda_0I)^{-1}q)\\
 &\qquad - \frac12q^\top (P + \lambda_0I)^{-1}q + r - \frac12\lambda_0\\
 &\ge - \frac12q^\top (P + \lambda_0I)^{-1}q + r - \frac12\lambda_0.
\end{align*}
On the other hand, let $x_0 := -(P + \lambda_0I)^{-1}q$
and we have $x_0^\top x_0 = 1$; Also, we have
\begin{align*}
 f(x_0) &= \frac12 q^\top (P + \lambda_0 I)^{-1} P (P + \lambda_0I)^{-1}q - q^\top (P + \lambda_0 I)^{-1}q + r\\
 &= \frac12 q^\top (P + \lambda_0 I)^{-1} (P + \lambda_0 I) (P + \lambda_0I)^{-1}q \\
 &\qquad - \frac12 q^\top (P + \lambda_0 I)^{-1} (\lambda_0 I) (P + \lambda_0I)^{-1}q\\
 &\qquad - q^\top (P + \lambda_0 I)^{-1}q + r\\
 &= - \frac12q^\top (P + \lambda_0I)^{-1}q + r - \frac12\lambda_0.
\end{align*}
Thus, the minimum of $f$ is $- \frac12q^\top (P + \lambda_0I)^{-1}q + r - \frac12\lambda_0$
at $x^\ast = -(P + \lambda_0I)^{-1}q$.
